# Magneto2 remove widget via xml in custom page

Tags: magento-2.1, cms-block, widget

In all cms pages i use widget. How can i remove widget by id on specific CMS pages? For remove block i use:

```
    <referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true"/>
```

Comment: First create a custom container. Then place that widget inside that container. Use referenceContainer to remove that container on specific pages.